# I have two tenants of Azure active directory.How to filter users per tenant id in Microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have two tenants of Azure Active Directory.
I am creating a console/Daemon/Background application which uses Microsoft.Graph nugget package.

How can I use microsoft graph api to filter based on tenant id?
Example I want to get users in particular tenant.There is no user login screen.I am using this https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-snippets-sample as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only authenticate against one tenant at a time so there is no method/need to filter by the tenant id. Each tenant would generate it's own Access Token for your application which you then return to that tenant as part of the request.

Comment: I have used this authority  static string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/";  for creating graph client.This way we can filter the users per tenant right?

Comment: Not exactly. Using `/{tenant}/` instead of `/common/` simply restricts authentication to users _from_ that tenant. In other words, if I authenticate using `login.microsoftonline.com/common`, it will result in the same token as I would get using my tenant's id.

Comment: In case I am tenant user of one tenant and guest user in another tenant. I can get authenticated for both the tenants.If I use login.microsoftonline.com{tenant}/ for authentication will that not get different token for various tenants. This token later can be used to get users of particular tenant.Will this not work?

Comment: Yes, but you have to authenticate twice. 1 Token -> 1 Tenant

Comment: Fair enough.Thanks.